# SQL if breaking number pattern, mark record?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have the following query:

```
SELECT AccountNumber, RptPeriod
FROM dbo.Report
ORDER BY AccountNumber, RptPeriod.
```

I get the following results:

```
123   200801
123   200802
123   200803
234   200801
344   200801
344   200803
```

I need to mark the record where the rptperiod doesnt flow concurrently for the account. For example 344 200803 would have an X next to it since it goes from 200801 to 200803.

This is for about 19321 rows and I want it on a company basis so between different companies I dont care what the numbers are, I just want the same company to show where there is breaks in the number pattern.

Any Ideas??

Thanks!

Comment: Is there at most one match for each `AccountNumber`, `RptPeriod`? combination (no duplicates)

Comment: yes there is only 1 report period that can be the same for a company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, this is kind of ugly (double join + anti-join) but it gets the work done, AND is pure portable SQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   dbo.Report R1
     , dbo.Report R2
WHERE  R1.AccountNumber = R2.AccountNumber
AND    R2.RptPeriod - R1.RptPeriod > 1
-- subsequent NOT EXISTS ensures that R1,R2 rows found are "next to each other",
-- e.g. no row exists between them in the ordering above
AND    NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Report R3
        WHERE  R1.AccountNumber = R3.AccountNumber
        AND    R2.AccountNumber = R3.AccountNumber
        AND    R1.RptPeriod < R3.RptPeriod
        AND    R3.RptPeriod < R2.RptPeriod
        )
```

Comment: I suppose that in the first where it´s R2.RptPeriod - R1.RptPeriod > 1 and in the NOT EXISTS is R2.RptPeriod > R3.RptPeriod

Comment: This appears to return no results at all against the OP's sample data.

Comment: @DVK - Your edit still doesn't work. It only returns one row.

Comment: @Martin - isn't there only 1 break in the original data?

Comment: @DVK - Yes. But as far as I understood (and Philip's answer does the same) the OP wants all rows back with `X` marking that particular row. So not sure if you need to use an outer join somewhere...

Comment: NOt exaclty what I was looking for but it works for what I'm doing!

Comment: @Martin - there may be a better way to do the "all rows with X" than applying outer join to my already joined-to-the-hilt query. Like selecting out all rows into temp table first, then updating via an anti-join to mark all rows that don't have a "next number" row and then updating again to remove the marks from "per-account max rows".

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
--  cte lists all items by AccountNumber and RptPeriod, assigning an ascending integer
--  to each RptPeriod and restarting at 1 for each new AccountNumber
;WITH cte (AccountNumber, RptPeriod, Ranking)
 as (select
        AccountNumber
       ,RptPeriod
       ,row_number() over (partition by AccountNumber order by AccountNumber, RptPeriod) Ranking
      from dbo.Report)
 --  and then we join each row with each preceding row based on that "Ranking" number
 select
    This.AccountNumber
   ,This.RptPeriod
   ,case
      when Prior.RptPeriod is null then ''  --  Catches the first row in a set
      when Prior.RptPeriod = This.RptPeriod - 1 then ''  --  Preceding row's RptPeriod is one less that This row's RptPeriod
      else 'x'  --  --  Preceding row's RptPeriod is not less that This row's RptPeriod
    end  UhOh
  from cte This
   left outer join cte Prior
    on Prior.AccountNumber = This.AccountNumber
     and Prior.Ranking = This.Ranking - 1
```

(Edited to add comments)

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH T
     AS (SELECT *,
                /*Each island of contiguous data will have 
                  a unique AccountNumber,Grp combination*/
                RptPeriod - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AccountNumber 
                                               ORDER BY RptPeriod ) Grp,
                /*RowNumber will be used to identify first record
                per company, this should not be given an 'X'. */
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AccountNumber 
                                       ORDER BY RptPeriod ) AS RN
         FROM   Report)
SELECT AccountNumber,
       RptPeriod,
       /*Check whether first in group but not first over all*/
       CASE
         WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AccountNumber, Grp 
                                     ORDER BY RptPeriod) = 1
              AND RN > 1 THEN 'X'
       END AS Flag
FROM   T
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  *
FROM   report r
LEFT   JOIN report r2
ON     r.accountnumber = r.accountnumber
AND    {r2.rptperiod is one day after r.rptPeriod}
JOIN   report r3
ON     r3.accountNumber = r.accountNumber
AND    r3.rptperiod > r1.rptPeriod
WHERE  r2.rptPeriod IS NULL
AND    r3 IS NOT NULL
```

I'm not sure of sql servers date logic syntax, but hopefully you get the idea.  r will be all the records where the next rptPeriod is NULL (r2) and there exists at least one greater rptPeriod (r3).  The query isn't super straight forward I guess, but if you have an index on the two columns, it'll probably be the most efficent way to get your data.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you number rows within every account, then, using the row numbers, compare the `RptPeriod` values for the neighbouring rows.

It is assumed here that `RptPeriod` is the year and month encoded, for which case the year transition check has been added.

```
;WITH Report_sorted AS (
  SELECT
    AccountNumber,
    RptPeriod,
    rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AccountNumber ORDER BY RptPeriod)
  FROM dbo.Report
)
SELECT
  AccountNumber,
  RptPeriod,
  CASE ISNULL(CASE WHEN r1.RptPeriod / 100 < r2.RptPeriod / 100 THEN 12 ELSE 0 END
              + r1.RptPeriod - r2.RptPeriod, 1) AS Chk
    WHEN 1 THEN ''
    ELSE 'X' 
  END
FROM Report_sorted r1
  LEFT JOIN Report_sorted r2
    ON r1.AccountNumber = r2.AccountNumber AND r1.rownum = r2.rownum + 1
```

It could be complicated further with an additional check for gaps spanning a year and more, if you need that.